DeepLinks and WebCredentials on Ionic Capacitor App
I am having serious issues on let these 2 things working. I finally succeeded few days ago, now, after some modification to the App, it doesn't work anymore. I have followed all the steps, but nothing.

'Branch' test passed
myapp:// on safari, correctly opens the App on my iphone

Let'say https://my-app.it is the web domain, and myapp:// is the scheme to open the App on device.
This is my configuration:
Environment
ionic --version
7.2.0

node --version
v20.11.1

package.json
"@ionic/angular": "^8.2.2",
"@capacitor/app": "^6.0.0",
"@capacitor/haptics": "^6.0.0",
"@capacitor/ios": "6.1.0",
"@capacitor/keyboard": "^6.0.1",
"@capacitor/splash-screen": "^6.0.1",
"@capacitor/status-bar": "^6.0.0",
"capacitor-ios-autofill-save-password": "^3.0.0",

src/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
(reachable and served as json. It passed also this branch test
{
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [
      "{{TEAM-ID}}.{{BUNDLE_ID}}"
    ]
  },
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [{
      "appID": "{{TEAM-ID}}.{{BUNDLE_ID}}",
      "paths": ["*"]
    }]
  }
}

capacitor.config.ts
in appId I put just bundle_id, without TEAM_ID as prefix, as suggested in docs.
import type { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: '{{BUNDLE_ID}}',
  appName: 'My App',
  webDir: 'www',
  bundledWebRuntime: false, 
  server: {
    hostname: 'my-domain.it', // webcredentials
    androidScheme: 'https'
  }
};

export default config;


info.plist
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>it.my-domain.deeplink</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>myapp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>it.my-domain.webcredentials</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>my-domain.it</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>

In Xcode, Signing&Capabilities, has "Associated Domains" with
- webcredentials:my-domain.it
- applinks:my-domain.it

What am I missing?
